# Ansible playbook failing with "/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file" on a Debian 5 target

Tags: linux, debian, ansible

A playbook I'm using is failing mysteriously on a client's legacy Debian 5 box. The playbook itself and my Ansible configuration are solid, and I've been running them successfully against a variety of old and new hosts, ranging from CentOS 6 and 7.x boxes to Debian 10, but this one machine is giving me trouble, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a failing minimal example playbook:

```
- hosts: deb5
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: random test task
      shell:
        cmd: "sed -e 's/netmask/netflask/' /etc/network/interfaces"
      register: test_out
      failed_when: no

    - debug: var=test_out
```

Here's the corresponding inventory:

```
# my ansible.cfg has 'interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3' but I override it for
# the rare older machines without Python 3, like this one.
deb5 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
```

And finally the ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
remote_user = some_user
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3

[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_ask_pass = True
become_flags = -i
```

The playbook is run with no other parameters than `-i inventory` and the playbook name. Here's the output of the debug task, showing the captured output of the failing `shell` `sed` task:

```
ok: [deb5] => {
    "test_out": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n",
        "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file\r\n",
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
        "rc": 126
    }
}
```

The `sed` task that gets run is not at fault here, and could be any other one as far as I've seen (I also tried `command` instead of `shell`, and running `awk` rather than `sed`). This is further evidenced by the fact that if I take out `gather_facts: no`, the playbook fails in the fact gathering phase already, never making it to the task:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
fatal: [deb5]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 126}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}
```

Based on googling, "cannot execute binary file" often indicates an architecture mismatch, but I don't see how this would apply here. When I SSH to the server and run any of the commands involved (`/bin/sh`, `/usr/bin/python`, `sed`), they all work fine. My macOS Ansible controller is x86_64, as is the Debian 5 box, according to `uname -m`.

One notable thing about the Debian 5 box is that its Python is very old, version 2.5.2. Ansible only supports Pythons from 2.6 up on target machines at the moment, I think. However, this is likely not the culprit here, since even the `raw` module (which operates without Python, and can be used to install Python on hosts without it) fails:

```
# Debian 5
- hosts: deb5
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: random test task
      raw: "sed -e 's/netmask/netflask/' /etc/network/interfaces"
      register: test_out
      failed_when: no

    - debug: var=test_out
```

The output in that case:

```
ok: [deb5] => {
    "test_out": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "msg": "non-zero return code",
        "rc": 126,
        "stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed."
        ],
        "stdout": "/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file\r\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file"
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't know enough about Ansible internals or its operating principles to come up with any other tests I could do, so I hope someone here has some further ideas.

Comment: Is `/bin/sh` actually executable on the target host?

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that it (and `sed`, `python`, etc.) all work fine when executed in a terminal session in the middle there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out this is not an Ansible issue. This seems to be a problem with sudoing on the target host that I can replicate over a simple SSH connection.

Comment: Specifically, it was this: https://mailing.unix.sudo-users.narkive.com/v7uQkeON/sudo-users-sudo-i-command-results-in-cannot-execute-binary-file (sudo < 1.7.0 does not support "sudo -i", which Ansible used due to me setting `become_flags = -i`